# jQuery.Marquee plugin: Scroll left AND text-align left from the beginning

Tags: jquery, marquee

I made this to show what I currently have working:

http://jsfiddle.net/53ceq/10/

As stated, I'd like to have the text scroll left, which is currently occurring.

**How do I set the text to the left (within the div) initially though?**

I've tried `text-align: left;` but this does not have an effect. Even if I set a `<div>` within the marquee div and try to modify the position on that, there is also no effect on the alignment: the text always 'pops out' from the right.

Note: this is based on https://github.com/aamirafridi/jQuery.Marquee

Any way around this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're styling the wrong element. Since JavaScript is setting some inline styles, you'll have to override them.

```
.js-marquee-wrapper {
    position: relative;
    left: -100%;
}
```

Its recommended though you just fork jQuery.Marquee, add this feature in, then remove this intrusive CSS.

Working Example: http://jsfiddle.net/MattLo/53ceq/12/

Comment: Hi Matt, thanks for the response. I see what you did but now the text isn't moving. Even if I add a `<div class="js-marquee-wrapper">` around my existing div I'm not getting any movement. Something I am missing?

Comment: Moves on Chrome 32.x but not Firefox 26.x. Probably because of selector specificity deltas for animation. I changed properties so there's no conflict. I've updated the post.

Comment: Actually Matt, minor issue: Using the wrapper CSS aligns the text correctly, but it throws off the natural cycle left of the text: after doing the initial cycle the next just kinda reappears. What would be the reasoning for this? http://jsfiddle.net/4QYJQ/31/

Comment: You're going to have to modify the `jQuery.Marquee` library since its dictating all of the spacing on iteration (via CSS3 animation injection). You could just hack around it though and modify the CSS on a parallel timer. http://jsfiddle.net/MattLo/53ceq/15/ (note that this is a hack...)